# How to generate Swagger json/yaml files from static code (Java)?

Tags: java, automation, continuous-integration, swagger

Are there any libraries out there that can generate the JSON/YAML file by analysing static code and generating the JSON/YAML files off of that?

Right now we're producing the Swagger files once the project has finished building. We hit the url at /api/swagger.yaml and do what we need with the file (this adds quite a bit of complexity to our automated builds)

Comment: Im unaware if it exists, but do you use a framework like spring? if yes, it's worth mentioning it, if no, i don't think a solution exists

Comment: @Kepotx no we're not using Spring. It's a Java SE with Maven project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes so as you are sort of doing already you can stick that in your CI which would startup this dummy Spring app then make a HTTP request to download the JSON/YAML then shut it down and get the file, as far as I am aware there are no tools that do this at compile time for Java and that's as good as it gets.

The other way is if you do things in opposite where you first design your API interface in swagger and then you generate code (your interfaces) which you then implement yourself.

From the sounds of it you want to be designing your API first, this will allow you to put it in version control and this will make it easier to manage your API versions life cycle and track it's changes, otherwise it can be quite difficult to see how things have changed if you have to search through annotated methods in code, that is what swagger is designed for.

You don't necessarily need to do codegen from your swagger as I have found this to be very awkward at times and it is extremely dumb and generating code, it's just moustache templating and IMO the tool is fundamentally flawed for this reason, but as my most hated saying goes:

> it's free so you can't complain